Teenage Movie, Two Girls Fall for the Same Guy
Ok so this is a movie I had seen around 10 years ago extremely late at night, so you know it was one of those lousy-looking ones with really bad acting. If I had to guess, it was probably filmed in the 1980s since some of the kids in this movie had really bad fashion sense and horrible hairstyles.
Key points:

It's a typical teen movie about kids in school somewhere in USA I think.
At the time when I saw this movie, I did not know any of the actors and actresses as they did not appear to be well-known. I'm expecting all of them to be randoms, unknowns and not popular at all. I wouldn't be surprised if this is the only movie they played in.
I remember one of the key characters was a school kid named James who had puffy blonde hair, wore a black leather jacket, looked anorexic or something, and I think two girls in the movie were really into him.
At some point in the movie, one of the girls gets really sad (maybe because she found out this James dude was dating someone else?). A scene between her and her friend unfolds like this (I think this happens in a stairwell at school):


Girl A: "Tell me what's wrong." (she then grabs the hand of Girl B)
Girl B: "Only if you let go of my hand..."

Both girls in this scene deliver their lines dry and with the most unconvincing display of acting I have ever seen. It is probably the reason why I remember just these lines from the movie and laugh every time.
That's all I remember, if anyone has any clue on what this movie is called, that would be awesome.

Possibly Two Girls and a Guy.
Two women (Heather Graham, Natasha Gregson Wagner) confront their boyfriend (Robert Downey Jr.), a two-timing actor who professed eternal love to each.   

Thanks for the suggestion, I haven't seen this movie so I'll have a look but I have the impression this wouldn't be it. The one I saw had all unknown actors and actresses in it. I have just updated the question to include this information as well.
